# Video lecture on multivariate analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, online-resources

Preferably covering the second half of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

I've been looking for such a course within my university but couldn't find it. Does anyone know of any decent video lectures covering these topics?

Comment: You could try MIT OCW, they have a multivariable course. It's probably not advanced enough for you though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really underrated collection of mathematics and other video lectures
http://nptel.ac.in/course.php

For your purpose: 
http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111104024/